# Modulation of voice

Tags: modulation

I apologize in advance if the question is very basic. When I google modulation all I read are the techniques that are used to modulate a signal.

I start from basic. Let's say I am a reporter and the wave sound of my voice changes all the time, meaning its amplitude and frequency at the same time. Now from what I read in order to send this sound wave I need a carrier wave with high frequency. There are three types of modulation that can be used (AM,FM, and PM).

But how can I pick either FM or AM when the sound of my voice change its amplitude and frequency at the same time every second? I want to get the same wave sound at the receiver and I don't understand how a complicated signal can be transferred by just transferring its amplitude change to the carrier (in case of AM).

Comment: Can you please try to clarify your question as at the moment it appears to be too broad? In the meantime, please see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_system) and [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demodulation)

Comment: uhm, your voice is an **audio signal** and the AM or FM or PM transmission of it would be a **radio signal**.  the amount of amplitude deviation for AM or the amount of frequency deviation for FM depends not on the **change**, but on the instantaneous value of your voice signal at a specific instance of time.

Comment: The following book(s) discusses a lot of mathematical and technical details of voice(speech) production and hearing mechanisms: 1-Speech and Hearing for Communications_H.Fletcher , 2-Speech and Audio Signal Processing_B.Gold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the source of your confusion, but here's a basic explanation. Say your voice is represented by the signal $s(t)$, and that its spectrum exists over the frequency range $f=0$ to $f=B$. Then, the signal $$r(t)=s(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)$$ has a spectrum that exists over the range $f_c-B$ to $f_c+B$. You can choose $f_c$ to suit your needs.

Now, at the receiver you want to obtain $s(t)$ from $r(t)$. So, you can calculate $$s(t)=\text{LPF}\lbrace r(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t) \rbrace,$$ where $\text{LPF}\lbrace\cdot\rbrace$ is a low-pass filter.

All these equations can be derived using just basic Fourier analysis.

Let me try to get back to your question. The voice signal $s(t)$ has instantaneous frequency and amplitude, as you say. These are conveyed perfectly to the carrier when you generate $r(t)$. The term "amplitude modulation" means that the voice signal's "properties" are imprinted on the carrier's amplitude; it does not mean that the instantaneous frequency of $s(t)$ is ignored by the communication process.

The same for FM: the whole of $s(t)$, including its instantaneous amplitude and frequency, are conveyed in the frequency of the carrier. Doing frequency modulation does not mean that that amplitude of the modulating signal $s(t)$ is not transmitted.

Feel free to elaborate on your question, as A_A suggests, if this answer does not help.